# yii bootstrap expand not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Hye there i design my website using yii bootstrap and i have a problem when i open my website and it reach certain resolution my menu will collapse and there are showing in drop down list. Right now when i click my account or manage button it does not expand until the end of the content i need to scroll down. But when i pressed the collapse to close it and i open it back it is working fine. It does not work only for the first time. Is it a bug or there it is something wrong from my side. Below is my code:

You can check using ur smartphones from my website

`This is my website: smartmobilelibrary.com
 username: tester@tester.com
 password: tester`

This is my main page(Admin)

```
<?php

$menu = array(
    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
    array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
    array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
);

if (Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()) {
    $menu = array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'Manage', 'url'=>'#', 'items' => array(
            array('label' => 'Manage Genres', 'url' => array('/categories/admin')),
            array('label' => 'Manage Courses', 'url' => array('/courses/admin')),
            array('label' => 'Manage Books', 'url' => array('/books/admin')),
            array('label' => 'Manage Bookings', 'url' => array('/bookings/admin')),
            array('label' => 'Manage Users', 'url' => array('/users/admin')),
        )),
        array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
        array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
    );      
} elseif (!empty(Yii::app()->user->id)) {
    $menu = array(
        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
        array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
        array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact'))
    );      
}

?>
```

This is my main page(User)

```
<?php 

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
'collapse'=>true,
'type' => '',
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'items'=>$menu
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
        'items' => array(
         array('label'=>'Account', 'url'=>'#', 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest, 'items' => array(


                array('label'=>'Book Recommendation', 'url'=>array('/users/recommendation')),
                array('label'=>'Booking History', 'url'=>array('/users/history')),
                array('label'=>'Update Profile', 'url'=>array('/users/profile')),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            )),

            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Register', 'url'=>array('/users/create'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),

        )
    )
),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `('class'=>'nav-collapse'),`

I should add on `('class'=>'nav-collapse collapse'),`

This is code from my TbNavbar:

```
if ($this->collapse !== false)
    {
        $this->controller->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCollapse', array(
            'id'=>$collapseId,
            'toggle'=>false, // navbars should be collapsed by default
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'nav-collapse collapse'),
        ));
    }
```

Comment: great! was looking for this for a long time. 
it worked like a charm!
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is because in your generated div

`<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" id="yii_bootstrap_collapse_0" style="height: 176px;">`

the height is not set to "auto" first time around but fixed to a computed value "176px" in this case , this is by design limitation to fix animation issues in bootstrap some versions of bootstrap 2.x

see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5671

if you upgrade the underlying bootstrap libs of yii-boostrap to 2.3.x it will be fixed

Comment: thanks alot man u are my savior i finally found it and i post and answer where i rectify the problem

Comment: You can also perhaps raise a pull request with the extension owner it will benefit everyone :).. although AFAIK Christopher is no longer maintaining Yii-bootstrap and moved to Yii-booster (backward compatible), and then i think to Yii-strap/Yii-wheels (not compatible with Yii-bootstrap)